# Implicit form to explicit form $\frac{e^{2y}}{y}= e^{5x} \Big (\frac{x}{5} + \frac{1}{25}\Big) + C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I'm trying to write this implicit solution in explicit form.  The $y$ in the denominator is messing me up.  Sorry about the formatting.

$$\frac{e^{2y}}{y}= e^{5x} \Big (\frac{x}{5} + \frac{1}{25}\Big)  +  C$$

I need to solve for $y$.  Maybe I'm not seeing the algebraic technique.  I tried to take the $\ln$ of both sides but then ended up with $\dfrac{2y}{\ln y}$.  Any idea how I can isolate the $y$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to solve for $y$ $$e^{2y}=Ay$$ The only explicit solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
$$y=-\frac{1}{2} W\left(-\frac{2}{A}\right)$$ The wikipedia page shows many examples of the manipulations to be done.